# List of List but by output is not coming right

Tags: java, collections

I have been trying to insert list of integer to another list but it seems i am making some mistake my output is not coming correct could anyone please help?
You can also comment http://goo.gl/xdLP9H

```
public class ListInsideList {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        originalList.add(i);//adding values to list
    }
    for(Integer value : originalList){
       tempList.add(value);
       if(tempList.size()==5)
       {
            newList.add(tempList);
            System.out.println("iteration:"+newList);
            tempList.clear();//clearing list
       }
    }
    System.out.println("final:"+newList);

  }
}
```

Output:

```
iteration:[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
final :[[], []]
required is:iteration:[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
final:[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: By the way, if my answer did indeed solve it, it's polite to mark it as "accepted". Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your final answer requires there be 2 separate lists.

- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // List One`
- `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // List Two`

So where do you create these two separate lists? You don't, you're just re-using the same `tempList` on each iteration. Adding `tempList` to another `List` doesn't divorce it from the variable name of "**tempList**" which is a reference to the same object which you then `clear()`.

Instead of `clear()`, create a new one each time:

- Instead of `tempList.clear(); //clearing list`
- Use `tempList = new ArrayList<>(); // new List`

Comment: Thanx it solved my problem but i am not getting the point why that happend It is not the same case when we clear the list is like creating the new one only 
can u please explain

Comment: Huh? By clearing the `List` you are emptying it and then re-using it for the 2nd iteration. When you add the `tempList` to the `newList` List of Lists, it retains a reference to the same object which you then clear. You need to create a totally new `List`

Comment: It's not the same. When you do `newList.add(templist)` you actually add a reference to the same templist object to the newList, not a clone of it. Thus, when you clear it, it clears everywhere it exists

Comment: @Stewart Yup. Basic Java stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `newList.add(tempList);` with:

1.

note: for this to work, your tempList must be a ArrayList (for List isn't serializable);

```
newList.add(SerializationUtils.clone(tempList));
templist.clear();
```

2.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(newList.size());
list.addAll(newList);
newList.add(list);
newList.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but using clone i m getting
Final : [[], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]] 
with some empty element aslo'

Comment: Maybe you forgot to delete the newList.add(tempList); line?

Answer (score 1):

Your Lists are empty in the final print statement. There is nothing for it to print since both the lists are empty as shown,

```
        System.out.println("final:"+newList.get(0).isEmpty());
```

and

```
    System.out.println("final:"+newList.get(1).isEmpty());
```

so instead try,

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        originalList.add(i);//adding values to list
    }

    for(Integer value : originalList){
       tempList.add(value);
       if(tempList.size()==5)
       {
            newList.add(tempList);              
            System.out.println("iteration:"+newList);
            finalList = newList;
       }

    }
    System.out.println("final:"+finalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this for minimal workload:

change

```
newList.add(tempList)
```

to

```
newList.add(newArrayList<Integer>(tempList));
```

in order to copy tempList and not using it's reference

```
for(Integer value : originalList){
       tempList.add(value);
       if(tempList.size()==5)
       {
            newList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(tempList));
            System.out.println("iteration:"+newList);
            tempList.clear();//clearing list
       }
    }
    System.out.println("final:"+newList);
```

Comment: It's worth explaining which line you've changed, and why